# Odds of outcome at least once over N repeated observations

Tags: probability

A friend suggested that if the odds of something happening to you in one year is `P`, the probability of it happening over `N` years is `N x P`.  That immediately seemed wrong to me because it would mean that the odds of having at least one tail over three coin tosses would be 150%.  I also told him that the probability of having at least one tail over two coin tosses is not 100%, which would be `.50 x 2` but 75% as the equally probably possible outcomes are:

```
H-H
H-T
T-H
T-T
```

Where all but the first possibility applies.

However, I would like to be reminded of what the exact formula for the odds of an outcome appearing at least once over N repeated observations is.  E.g. if your odds of dying on a particular ski slope is 2%, how do you calculate the odds you will die if you go down 50 times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $p$ is the probability that the event will occur in any given attempt, then $1-p$ is the probability that it *won’t* occur in any given attempt. Assuming that the attempts are independent, the probability that you get through $n$ attempts without it occurring even once is therefore $(1-p)^n$: it fails to happen on every one of those $n$ attempts. Thus, the probability that it *does* happen at least once in $n$ attempts is $1-(1-p)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing multiplication and taking powers. If the probability of getting heads is $0.50$, then the probability of getting three heads in a row is $0.50^3 = 0.125$, not $0.50 \times 3 = 1.50$. In the case of independent events, you want to multiply the probabilities, not multiply the probability with the number of times you try.

Comment: I am not confusing it, i used it as a wrong example...  or as an example of wrong